# Cada vez que intento actualizar un registro con Python y Mysql no actualiza el registro solo genera uno nuevo

Tags: python, sql

A este metodo le paso el array llamado DAN que contiene los datos que deseo actualizar en la tabla y con el format los arreglo para que se posicionen en cada uno de los campos de la tabla

````
def actaNacimientoUpdate(self, DAN):
        
        if  self.connection.is_connected():

            cursor = self.connection.cursor() 
            
            sql = "UPDATE acta_nacimiento SET nombres = '{0}', apellidos = '{1}', fecha_nacimiento = '{2}', hora_nacimiento = '{3}', lugar_nacimiento = '{4}', sexo = '{5}', cedula_padre = {6}, nombre_padre = '{7}', apellido_padre = '{8}', cedula_madre = {9}, nombre_madre = '{10}', apellido_madre = '{11}', id_prefectura = {12} WHERE nro_acta = {13}"

            cursor.execute(sql.format(DAN[0], DAN[1], DAN[2], DAN[3], DAN[4], DAN[5], DAN[6], DAN[7], DAN[8], DAN[9], DAN[10], DAN[11],DAN[12],DAN[13]))
            self.connection.commit()
            cursor.close()```
````

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que se ejecuta este método? Un UPDATE no inserta nuevas filas. Si se está ejecutando esto, revisa los triggers en la tabla. Por lo pronto, no hay información suficiente para saber cual es el problema.

Comment: Bueno acabo de revisar el codigo y coloqué la funcion de insertar en vez de la de actualizar, Gracias por la ayudaa